# Python pandas trouble with storing result in variable

Tags: python, csv, variables, pandas

I'm using pandas to handle some csv file, but i'm having trouble storing the results in a variable and printing it out as it is.

This is the code that I have.

```
df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE.csv, index_col=False, header=0)
df2 = df[(df['Name'])]
# Trying to get the result of Name to the variable
n = df2['Name']
print(n)
```

And the result that i get:

```
1    jake
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

My Question:

Is it possible to just have "Jake" stored in a variable "n" so that i can call it out whenever i need it?

EG: Print (n)

Result: `Jake`

**This is the code that I have constructed**

```
def name_search():

    list_to_open = input("Which list to open: ") + ".csv"
    directory = "C:\Users\Jake Wong\PycharmProjects\box" "\\" + list_to_open
    if os.path.isfile(directory):

# Search for NAME
        Name_id = input("Name to search for: ")
        df = pd.read_csv(directory, index_col=False, header=0)
        df2 = df[(df['Name'] == Name_id)]

        # Defining the name to save the file as
        n = df2['Name'].ix[1]

        print(n)
```

**This is what is in the csv file**

```
S/N,Name,Points,test1,test2,test3
s49,sing chun,5000,sc,90 sunrsie,4984365132
s49,Alice Suh,5000,jake,88 sunrsie,15641816
s1231,Alice Suhfds,5000,sw,54290 sunrsie,1561986153
s49,Jake Wong,5000,jake,88 sunrsie,15641816
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `n = df2['Name']` is actually a Pandas Series:

```
type(df.loc[df.Name == 'Jake Wong'].Name)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

If you just want the value, you can use `values[0]` -- values is the underlying array behind the Pandas object, and in this case it's length 1, and you're just taking the first element.

```
n = df2['Name'].values[0]
```

Also your CSV is not formatted properly: It's not enough to have things lined up in columns like that, you need to have a consistent delimiter (a comma or a tab usually) between columns, so the parser can know when one column ends and another one starts. Can you fix your csv to look like this?:

```
S/n,Name,points
s56,Alice Suh,5000
s49,Jake Wong,5000
```

Otherwise we can work on another solution for you but we will probably use regex rather than pandas.

Comment: Hmm, I have another qns though. It seems that if the name has 2 words, "Jake Wong", it throws an error? KeyError: 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone has any idea about how this can be solved if its 2 or more words?

Comment: hey jake can you paste the text of your csv and your exact code? you shouldn't have a problem with spaces in a string column.

Comment: I have added the code i've used, and data from my csv file above. does it help makes things clearer? Thanks again for taking time to help me with my problem!

Comment: hey jake i've added a bit more info in the answer

Comment: Hey, ok i've changed the csv to be as such. But i'm still getting errors.. I really dont understand what could be wrong.. without `ix[1]` it displays the whole column / row perfectly. but its just not able to store the names in the variable.. :(

Comment: I was reading the documentation and noticed something. `ix[1]` would only return what is at entry number 1.. meaning to say, based on my csv, it will only return entry if value is `Alice Suh` if it is anything else. it will return `error message`. I tried testing this out by changing the numbers and typing the corresponding names along with it, and it seems to be correct. But unfortunately, it still doesn't solve my problem. lol...  Thoughts?

Comment: Hey Jake, I misunderstood your question, I've edited my answer again. You actually want to do `n = df2['Name'].values[0]`